# UriComponentsBuilder's queryParam method

Tags: spring

When i use UriComponentsBuilder, there are times when i want the queryParam method to short circuit if the value is null or empty.

Here is how UriComponentsBuilder currently works.

```
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder
    .fromUriString("test/customerUriComponentsBuilder")
    .queryParam("a", (Object[]) null)
    .queryParam("b", "")
    .queryParam("c", new Object[1])
    .build().toUri();
assertEquals(uri.toASCIIString(),
    "test/customerUriComponentsBuilder?a&b=&c");
```

There are times when would like it to behave like this:

```
    URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder
    .fromUriString("test/customerUriComponentsBuilder")
    .queryParam("a", (Object[]) null)
    .queryParam("b", "")
    .queryParam("c", new Object[1])
    .build().toUri();
assertEquals(uri.toASCIIString(),
    "test/customerUriComponentsBuilder");
```

Currently, I cannot see a way to do this using the queryParam method.
Would it make sense to overload the queryParam method to accept a flag to short circuit?

Comment: Do you have the code where you would need such behaviour, because in this code sample, you clearly control a-b-c values, so I'm guessing this snippet is only some sample. Do you have the real code ?

Comment: So, Here is a simple example: URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder
    .fromUriString("test/customerUriComponentsBuilder")
    .queryParam("start", start)
    .queryParam("count", count)
    .build().toUri();

Comment: There are times when i have a bunch of optional queryParams and it seems like the queryParam method can handle it more gracefully, then trying to do a bunch of assertions before.

Comment: I don't want a simple example, I want the real code. If the values are hardcoded, as in your example, than the answer is to "not provide" a null value in the first place. So I'm guessing, since your are asking, the real code does not hardcode values, and they are coming from somewhere else. I guess, my answer is I think the input values should be check before using the Builder.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. I can make it work but i am wondering if they queryParam method can handle it more gracefully.